# Retrieve JSON Array from jQuery Ajax call in asp.net webpages

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, webmatrix

I am trying to send some data through an ajax call of jQuery. My question is : **how do I get hold of this JSON array in my `Insert.cshtml` file?** I have tried `Request["rows"]`, `Request[0][rows]`, etc. but without any success.

Here, the data I am trying to send is this (multiple rows of form data):

```
[
    {
        "sl": "1",
        "tname": "Gardening",
        "ttype": "4",
        "tduration": "12"
    },
    {
        "sl": "2",
        "tname": "Nursing",
        "ttype": "4",
        "tduration": "45"
    }
]
```

jQuery Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Insert",
    data: rows,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data, status) {
        alert(status);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        var errorMessage = error || xhr.statusText;
        alert(errorMessage);
    }
});
```

**Update: A partial demo in jsfiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/rafi867/gprQs/8/

Comment: @qwerty I am trying to access the values in the referred page (Insert.cshtml in this case), not in the current page. Anyhow, I guess what you suggested will bring an error like "the name 'data' does not exist in current context".

Comment: You don't happen to have a link to your site, do you? Or a jsfiddle?

Comment: @qwerty Here is something that I have on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gprQs/5/.
I don't really know how to simulate the call to another .cshtml page but I think you will get the idea.

Comment: I believe a similar question is this: http://bit.ly/UMdnQ2 but unfortunately that is also unanswered.

Comment: Sorry, i can't help you.

Comment: Is it OK to send json string as parameter to page? Index?str={your json here}?

Comment: @sgud I guess it is possible for simpler json objects but there will be problem if you have arrays/complex structure in your json objects.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to simulate your problem creating in App_Code a Sample.cs class:

```
public class Sample
{
    public string sl { get; set; }
    public string tname { get; set; }
    public string ttype { get; set; }
    public string tduration { get; set; }
}
```

Now your Insert.cshtml file should look like this:

```
@{
    var sample = new Sample[]{
    new Sample{ sl = "1", tname = "Gardening", ttype = "4", tduration = "12" },
    new Sample{ sl = "2", tname = "Nursing", ttype = "4", tduration = "45" }
    };
    Json.Write(sample, Response.Output);
}
```

and the file (ReadSample.cshtml?) that holds your Sample objects should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.getJSON('/Insert', function (sample)
            {
                var custList = "";
                $.each(sample, function (index, obj) {
                        custList += "<li>" + obj.sl + " - " + obj.tname + 
                                " - " + obj.ttype + " - " + obj.tduration + "</li>";
                })
                $("#list").html("<ul>" + custList + "</ul>")
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="list"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my example I have readed the objects array with

```
$.getJSON('/Insert', function (sample)
```

and created an unordered list to display its content

```
$.each(sample, function (index, obj) {
        custList += "<li>" + obj.sl + " - " + obj.tname + 
                " - " + obj.ttype + " - " + obj.tduration + "</li>";
})
$("#list").html("<ul>" + custList + "</ul>")
```

I hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

I have put a **sample code** for show how to display array items on web page by using jquery and css. By using this try to understand the concept and then apply it to your scenario.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="dialog" id="unpaid-dialog" data-width="550" data-title="Checkout">
        <ul>
            <li id="serviceAndRetailDetails" style="text-align: left;"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    var toBePaidItems = new Array();//create a array
    var make = "";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Portal/GetServiceAndRetailSalesDetails",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        data: { invoiceOrSaleId: invoiceOrSaleId, providerKey: providerKey },
        success: function (response) {
            make = "<table id='tblPayment'>";
            toBePaidItems = [];

            $.each(response, function (index, sr) {

                make += "<tr id=" + sr.AllocationOrInvoiceOrSaleId + " class=" + sr.Class + ">" + "<td style='padding-right:100px'>" + sr.Name + "</td><td class='colTotal' style='padding-right:45px'>" + '$ ' + sr.Price.toFixed(2) + "</td><td></tr>";

                //insert into array
                toBePaidItems.push(sr.AllocationOrInvoiceOrSaleId);
            });

            make += "</table>";
            $("#serviceAndRetailDetails").html(make);
        }
    });

</script>
```

**Controller Action Method**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetServiceAndRetailSalesDetails(Guid invoiceOrSaleId, string providerKey)
        {

            var items = new List<CheckOutServiceAndRetailItem>();

            var serviceDetails = Repository.GetAllPayableItems(invoiceOrSaleId).ToList();

            foreach (var s in serviceDetails)
            {
                var item = new CheckOutServiceAndRetailItem
                {
                    AllocationOrInvoiceOrSaleId = s.Allocation.AllocationId,
                    Name = s.Allocation.Service.Name,
                    Price = s.LatestTotal,
                    Class = s.Allocation.Service.IsAnExtra,
                };
                items.Add(item);
            }

            return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**Array Out Put**

[image]

How to manipulate Arrays [**Here**](http://thejimgaudet.com/articles/support/web/jquery-arrays-create-add-to-remove-from-and-compare/)

Hope This will help to you.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not really help me. I guess in MVC you can taget a function to receive the data; my question is how to do the similar thing for asp.net webpages.

Comment: @lazylionking from where you sending data ,is that from Insert.cshtml or from another web page? Can you explain the scenario with bit more details ?

Comment: I have a page (suppose, Default.cshtml) with a form, where user can add new rows if necessary and in the end, if they press submit, I want all the data (consisting of multiple rows) to be inserted in the database. As I cannot access the dynamically added rows with plain html, I am using jQuery to pack all the row in a json object and pass that to the Insert.cshtml file wchich is supposed to deal with database tasks. But I am failing to access the json object inside the Insert.cshtml file, and that is my question. For a partial overview, look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rafi867/gprQs/8/

Answer (score 0):

The data parameter is meant to map name-value pairs to query string parameters as you can tell by the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **data**
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
>   processData option to prevent this automatic processing. *Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs.* If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
>   values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting
>   (described below).

If you then go on to read the docs for the [`.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) method, this should help you understand what's going on with your request and how jQuery sends your object to the server.

You may just have to name your objects/arrays in your `data` object so you can refer to them in the `Request.Forms` object.