# How can I target a specific method in an external .cs file with a jQuery AJAX call in a WebMatrix C#.net environment?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webmatrix

If I have this JavaScript function:

```
function fillMainStreetEvent(location) { // /AJAX Pages/Compute_Main_Street_Event.cshtml
    $.ajax({
        url: "/App_Code/ContentGenerator.cs/ContentGenerator.GenerateMainStreetEvents",
        async: false,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        data: { page: location },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#MainStreetEvents").html(response);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
            alert("Oops! We're sorry, there has been an AJAX error. The server responded with (" + textStatus + ": " + error + ").");
        }
    });
}
```

And I want to target the method: `GenerateMainStreetEvents` of the class: `ContentGenerator` in an external file named: `ContentGenerator.cs`, how do I do this?

This was my latest attempt to target a single method within my `.cs` file, however, I am not surprised that I couldn't get it working since *guessing* is a horrible way to begin writing syntactically correct code.

In the first line's comment you can see the string I would normally use to point to an external `cshtml` file, which, functionally would serve me fine, especially since I can just call my external `.cs` file's method from there.  However, I am trying to reduce hops across files and began researching for ways to do this, but came up empty handed.

In addition to:

```
/App_Code/ContentGenerator.cs/ContentGenerator.GenerateMainStreetEvents
```

I have tried this:

```
/App_Code/ContentGenerator.cs/ContentGenerator/GenerateMainStreetEvents
```

This:

```
/App_Code/ContentGenerator.cs.ContentGenerator.GenerateMainStreetEvents
```

And this:

```
/App_Code/ContentGenerator.cs/GenerateMainStreetEvents
```

None of which have worked for me, considering my environment. The only online examples that I can find on how to do this involve PHP, classic ASP, or some other language I am not using with ASP.NET.

The answer here is probably something very simple, but since I have never targeted an external `.cs` file with AJAX before, I am all out of guesses and research is turning up no new ideas.

Answer (score 0):

So to start - your App_Code directory in any ASP.NET application should NEVER serve content.  This is to protect yourself from accidentally exposing your source code on your web site :) To get this rolling, you need to follow a few steps:

1. Create a new cshtml page named 'GenerateMainStreetEvents.cshtml'.
2. Inside of that page, add a razor block that invokes your GenerateMainStreetEvents function
3. After you have a list of objects in razor, you need to convert them into JSON.  I suggest using JSON.NET, which is available on NuGet:  http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx
4. Using Response.Write and Response.End to write out the JSON and end your HTTP response

Here is a really good example:
[Retrieve JSON Array from jQuery Ajax call in asp.net webpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916689/retrieve-json-array-from-jquery-ajax-call-in-asp-net-webpages)

Happy coding!

Comment: Just curious what you mean by "Never serve content"?